# ASP.NET Core Windows Authentication Form Post results in 405

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, http-post, windows-authentication

I am trying to submit a form (POST) with Windows Authentication, but every post results in 405 error.

```
2021-06-05T22:08:28.8167802-04:00 [INF] (/11) Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://app.domain.com/app/ - - - 200 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 134.8090ms
2021-06-05T22:08:51.5348941-04:00 [INF] (/6) Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://app.domain.com/app/Access/Requested application/x-www-form-urlencoded 301
2021-06-05T22:08:51.5367966-04:00 [INF] (/6) Authorization failed. "These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user."
2021-06-05T22:08:51.5371524-04:00 [INF] (/6) Executing endpoint '"405 HTTP Method Not Supported"'
2021-06-05T22:08:51.5374762-04:00 [INF] (/6) Executed endpoint '"405 HTTP Method Not Supported"'
2021-06-05T22:08:51.5392486-04:00 [INF] (/6) Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://app.domain.com/app/Access/Requested application/x-www-form-urlencoded 301 - 405 - - 4.3451ms
```

Upon re-deployment of the Web App, sometimes it works but fails again on the next deployment.
I have already uninstalled WebDAV Publishing from the server.

IIS has both Windows and Anonymous authentication enabled for this App.

Comment: Why do you have Anonymous authentication enabled? Pick one or the other, not both.

Comment: There are few controllers which needs to be Anonymous and hence enabled Anonymous